# setting up domain controller using Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I want to setup a domain controller a network that has none. I am not very good in Ubuntu but i want to use it on my server to provide AD, DHCP, DC , print server for the network that has only windows machines. Kindly advice if this is posible and ways applications that are needed.